# Is there any smart edge routing proxy mechanism available which could route request based on user credentials?

Tags: nginx, microservices, traffic

I want to implement routing to kubernetes cluster based on user credentials. Like for a specific user based on User Id, I want to redirect traffic to a specific node. Is it possible with some already available edge router e.g Traefix, nginx?

Answer (score 0):

You can do Canary deployments in Kubernetes based on url, you are looking a variation of it based on Specific User, I am not sure out of the mind, but you could probably read the user id from header and do different routes. You can find an example here, https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-canary-deployments-for-mere-mortals-13728ce032fe